# Email client not showing signed emails (mail is still on server)

Tags: email, htc-desire-hd, encryption

I'm having trouble reading signed emails (in the mail app, not gmail).

The email client only shows: "mail is still on server" message, not the email content.

Comment: Could you previously read encrypted E-mails via the E-mail app?

Comment: @JonnyP Nope. They are just signed, not encrypted. And desktop email clients have absolutely no trouble reading them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, this is simply a bug in the HTC email application. You can try using a different client ([K9](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.fsck.k9&hl=en) supports signed messages, I believe), but beyond that you'll have to take it up with HTC and hope that they decide to fix it at some point.

[Here's a related XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=558613) where someone includes what he says is a response from HTC regarding the issue. There's also [a thread](http://forum.androidcentral.com/htc-evo-4g/20453-htc-mail-app-broken.html) on the Android Central forums where someone reports the same bug (and no solution). Those threads are a little on the old side, but I don't believe HTC has fixed this yet.

Comment: I'm still in WTF mode. And probably won't get from it for some time :) Why the heck would the deliberately block signed emails? Thx for the info anyway.